# Passing Javascript Array to UILabel - iOS

Tags: javascript, ios, arrays, xcode, webview

I have a javascript array in a local HTML file in my app:

```
//js

<script language="javascript">
    test = ["First menu item","second menu item", "third menu item"];
</script>
```

and I would like to pass on this array to a UILabel in iOS. How could I go about doing this?

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Have you looked at the JavaScriptCore framework?

Comment: Yes. I am still in need of help however.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to do this with the steps below:

1. First, transform your javascript array of strings in just one
   string with the method `join()`
2. Second, use webview's method
       `stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:` to get the string above
3. Finally, using NSString's method `componentsSeparatedByString:`
       to transform the string in a iOS array of strings.

Now, you only have to use this array as datasource of your UIPickerView. You can see how to do this [here](http://www.leesilver.net/1/post/2011/07/uipickerview-how-to-populate.html).

This is how to code would look like:

Your javascript:

```
<script language="javascript">
    var test = ["First menu item","second menu item", "third menu item"];
    var testString = test.join('#');
</script>
```

Your objective-C code:

```
NSString *testArrayString = [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"testString"];
NSArray *testArray = [testArrayString componentsSeparatedByString:@"#"]; 
NSLog(@"%@", testArray);
```

Here's what the NSLog will print:

```
2013-08-20 23:48:29.578 YourProject3633:c07] (
    "First menu item",
    "second menu item",
    "third menu item"
)
```

EDIT:

To show the array content in a label, instead of a UIPickerView, you can do (untested, but should work):

```
self.myLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:%@, testArray];
```

or simply joining the array's strings again with a comma, like this:

```
self.myLabel.text = [testArray componentsJoinedByString:@","];
```

I don't know if someone has a better solution, this is the first thing I thought. Let me know if it helped you.

Comment: Thank You so much, but I get an error in the second line right after bracket in objective-c code. Use of undeclared identifier test. What should test be the UIPicker in the header file?

Comment: Sorry about the error, I just pasted wrong. That was supposed to be the string from javascript. Try again.

Comment: I am so sorry, but i'm just not familiar enough with using a picker view. If I just wanted to display in a UILabel how could I do that, I will update my question.

Comment: Dude, my answer was all about 'transforming' a javascript array in a objective-C array. You can see the array correctly mounted in the console after executed the `NSLog`. The UIPickerView part I left to you, is really basic. Just follow the link I posted (http://www.leesilver.net/1/post/2011/07/uipickerview-how-to-populate.html). You will only have to change his 'arrStatus' array by our 'testArray', the rest will be the same. Give a try, any other doubts you can ask later.

Comment: Glad to help again. Good Luck!